# Computer architectural performance analsyis - How to reduce unrelated performance counter events?

Tags: regression, correlation, mixed-model, repeated-measures, linear-model

Inside modern computer, there are thousands of performance counter events that can monitor various utilization such as cache bandwidth, I/O bandwidth, CPU stall cycles, etc.

Usually, with any application, there are a few parameters that we can configure to get different results. I **want to detect which performance counters have relationship/sensitivity/correlation with the parameter and ignore/filter those that are unrelated.** This way, we can zoom-in into performance bottleneck more effectively than go through thousands of events blindly.

For example,

```
Trial, Config parameter A, Performance Result, Made up performance result (fake)
1      0                   16.3                9.8
2      64                  17                  10
3      128                 17.7                9.9
4      256                 19.7                11
5      384                 22.5                9.7    
6      512                 27.4                11
7      768                 29.7                11
```

In the above example, I ran my program 7 times with change in parameter A, and obtained 7 results in the middle column. The Pearson's correlation between column 1 & 2 = 0.98 which is quite high, but then I made up a third column that simulate non-sensitive/no-correlation between parameter A and result, but I still got Pearson's correlation value of 0.67. Thus, I'm not sure if Pearson's correlation can really filter out no-correlation variables for my use cases.

I'm looking for suggestion and keywords on what I should be reading to programmatically remove non-significant variables.